# "Cannot execute binary" error in Linux emulator

Tags: linux, perl, cygwin

Apologies for not being well-versed in the world of computers! I'm trying to run some molecular dynamic simulations, using the Cygwin Linux emulator (64 bit) on a Windows machine. However I keep getting the error "cannot execute binary at ...." I've tried doing "dos2unix" to see if it's a language error. Googling says that it might be a 64/32 bit mismatch, but I thought it was fine to run 32 bit on a 64 bit? The code where it cannot execute binary is below:

```
BEGIN {
if ($ENV{'CHARMMEXEC'} ne "") {
    $exec=$ENV{'CHARMMEXEC'};
} else {
    $exec=&GenUtil::findExecutable("charmm");
}
```

...

```
my $charmmexec=shift;

if (defined $charmmexec) {
    $exec=$charmmexec;
}

die "cannot execute binary" if ((!-x $exec) && ($exec !~ "mpi") && ($exec !~ "ibrun"));
```

I'm not well-versed in perl so I don't understand most of what the code means, despite all my googling. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question and add a bit more of your code. We need to know what the variable `$exec` contains. That line of code says _throw that error_ if the value of `$exec` is not an executable file and the value does not contain the string _mpi_ in it and the value does not contain the string _ibrun_ in it. You need to find code that looks like `my $exec = ...` or just `$exec = ...` and add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This line will exit your program unless all four of these things are true.

1. The filename stored in the variable `$exec` contains the literal text `"ibrun"`
2. The filename stored in the variable `$exec` contains the literal text `"mpi"`
3. The file for the filename stored in the variable `$exec` can be accessed.
4. The file for the filename stored in the variable `$exec` has the executable permission bit set.

You could break this up into three statements to see which of these conditions isn't being met:

```
die "Expected $exec to contain 'ibrun'"             if $exec !~ "ibrun";
die "Expected $exec to contain 'mpi'"               if $exec !~ "mpi";
die "Can't stat $exec: $!"                          if !stat($exec);
die "$exec is not executable. Run 'chmod +x $exec'" if !-x _;
```

Comment: Great, that makes a ton more sense, thank you! Here's a bit more of the code as the user above suggested I include **if (defined $charmmexec) {
    $exec=$charmmexec;
  }** and **my $charmmexec=shift** (I'm not sure what this means? I can't find anything on =shift besides dealing with shifting arrays)

Comment: It could also be a permission error, or the file might be missing, etc. Updated answer to cover those situations.

Comment: Okay so it looks like **=shift** sets the variable to the default value--is that right?

Comment: Okay, I think I get it? The top is setting the variable 'exec' to be the path of the environment variable 'CHARMMEXEC.' Then the issue comes about because the text of "ibrun" and "mpi" are not in this variable. Alternatively, it is a permissions error (which I don't know how to check for). I'll try to figure out the first one first.

Answer (score 0):

Great thanks everyone! Looks like the issue was that CHARMMEXEC was not defined so it was just a matter of declaring it as an environment variable. Thanks again!

Comment: Please accept an answer, either this one since it specifies the exact root of the problem, or the other answer because it helped you discover the root cause.